# UEFI cannot launch grub after deleting linux partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, grub, uefi, boot-partition

I had set a multi partition system with ubuntu, kali and windows 10 and when i deleted both the linux distros and restarted my PC it booted into grub rescue mode (unknown filesystem).

If I hit up F12 on startup, under UEFI I can see windows, ubuntu and kali boot options and I can successfully boot from there to windows. But if I change to legacy boot, then i got a message saying that the relevant bootable device cannot be found.

Is it possible to install GRUB and boot windows 10 this way without having to enter F12 on boot?

P.S. This is a Dell system

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways to install GRUB:

You can install a legacy GRUB which only can be run in legacy mode. It has a start code in the master boot record which will load the main GRUB from the boot partition and configuration files in /boot/grub.

Alternatively you can install the UEFI version of GRUB (Ubuntu package grub-efi) which can only run if you firmware starts in UEFI mode. Here grubx64.efi and grub.cfg are installed on the EFI system partitions but the module files and the configuration still live in the boot partition.

I suggest you install the Ubuntu grub-efi and the shim packages and let the UEFI firmware start shimx64.efi by default.